# Intelij IDEA - UML plugin - generated diagram change colors

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, uml

How can I change colors in resulted diagram generated by Intellij IDEA UML plugin?

On image below you can see that actual colors are not readable. Diagram was generated from database.

I am not asking about how to change whole color scheme. I am satisfied with my color scheme. This is the only thing which I need to change.

UPDATE: @Andrey suggested how to change color of text from dark green to something else (Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Text | Default text). But I noticed that this dramatically changes other parts of my code editor. I am using light mode in IDE and I think that more useful will be to change background color from almost black to something lighter. So the question was specified more closely to "How to change background color in diagram generated by Intellij IDEA UML plugin?"

[image]

Comment: Do you have these tables/fields modified or added in Database? These could be colors from the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | **File Status Colors**. Otherwise, try Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Text | **Default text** colors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With "Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Text | Default text" I am able to change color of text from dark green to something else. But I noticed that this dramatically changes other parts of my code editor. I am using light mode in IDE and I think that more usefull will be to change background color from almost black to something lighter. Do you know how to change that? I will update my question regard to this.

Comment: The colors used in diagram are the same as the colors used in Editor for the default text. If you are using light mode - how do you generate Dark diagrams? How does your editor text and colors look like?

Comment: I have set in my Intellij these values: Theme: Intellij Light ; color scheme Panitent Light (rainglow). Have no idea why diagrams are dark that's the question.

Answer (score 5):

I have found it. If you are interested, this is where you can change background color in diagram generated by Intellij IDEA UML plugin:

- Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Diagrams | Node background
- Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Diagrams | Node header